# vuex function - returns true or false based on object value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a data that returns children object like below so `this.children` will return as below:

```
  {
    "1": {
      "firstName": "JJJ",
      "lastName": "B",
      "day": "1",
      "month": "1",
      "year": 2012,
      "name": "JJJ B",
      "dateOfBirth": "2012-01-01",
      "age": 6,
      "id": "1"
    },
    "2": {
      "firstName": "KKK",
      "lastName": "B",
      "day": "2",
      "month": "2",
      "year": 2004,
      "name": "KKK B",
      "dateOfBirth": "2004-02-02",
      "age": 14,
      "id": "2"
    },
    "3": {
      "firstName": "LLL",
      "lastName": "B",
      "day": "3",
      "month": "3",
      "year": 2017,
      "name": "LLL B",
      "dateOfBirth": "2017-03-03",
      "age": 1,
      "id": "3"
    }
  }
```

I want to make a function that returns true or false if the age of the child in that list is below 3. I'm pretty new to vue. I understand how to retrieve age when I'm using v-for but not sure how to proceed with vue function when it involves checking the object value.

Comment: show us the `v-for` loop and the element that wraps

Comment: @boussadjra         <ul v-for="child in childList"><li>{{child.age}}</li></ul>

Comment: i understood that you want to show only the persons who have age<3?

Comment: For now, I just want to show "true" or "false" if any of the children in the list is of age below 3.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```js
<ul v-for="child in getChildrenUnder3 "><li>{{child.age<3}}</li></ul>
```

or you can use the computed properties :

```js
computed:{
   getChildrenUnder3(){
   let children3=[];
   for(let i=0;i<Object.keys(this.childList).length;i++){
    if(Object.values(this.childList)[i].age<3){ 
    children3.push(Object.values(this.childList)[i])
   }
   }
   return  children3;
   }
}
```

and render it like that :

```js
<ul v-for="child in getChildrenUnder3 "><li>{{child.age}}</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

just put the function inside the template

```
<template>
  <div v-for="child in children" :key="child.id"> 
    {{child.firstName}} is less than three: {{child.age < 3 ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'}}
  </div>
</template>
```

If you however, are trying to find out if every child is less than 3, you can use a computed value to retrieve this data

the `minAge` should return the lowest age found

```
computed: {
  minAge() {
    return Math.min(Object.keys(this.children).map(k => {
      this.children[k].age;
    }))
  }
}
```

then you can use this to generate boolean in your template like this `{{minAge<3}}`